# Extracting hidden text with Selenium

Tags: selenium2

I'm trying to extract a certain message from my app. 
The text starts up as visible and then changes to `style= "visibility: hidden"`
the visibility period is rather short, and I was wondering how can I extract this text
using Selenium after it changes status to hidden.

I'm using a simple `element.getText()` command to get this text, which works when 
it's visible but returns nothing when hidden.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I used in Selenium Webdriver java for getting CheckBox text. My code which worked fine for me: String checkBoxLabel= (String)((JavascriptExecutor)Browser.driver) .executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML",checkLabelTextElement); System.out.println("CheckText is"+checkBoxLabel);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and actually dislike this "feature" in Selenium. In my C# abstraction layer I replaced `getText` with this:

```
return ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriverInstance).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", elementInstance).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, I will give this a try. I'm still kind of new to java and selenium so might take me some time to report if it worked

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly, instead of my element.getText(); I used 'JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
(js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", element)); and I get my value regardless of visibility status.

Comment: Oh, yeah i didn't notice that.....Done!

Comment: it extract tag and attribute too.. not only text

Comment: You are correct.  In C# I use this code to remove any tag info so that only inner text is displayed.
string returnText = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)WTWebUiAuto.webDriver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", this.WtElement).ToString();
returnText = Regex.Replace(returnText, "<.*?>", "");